# How to add multiple ID on an element in Twig

Tags: php, sql, symfony, twig

I need to add 2 different ID from 2 different table in my database (to get all informations about each `id`) in my URL.

I got this exception:

> Neither the property "car" nor one of the methods "car()", "getcar()"/"iscar()"/"hascar()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Quote".

I'm not good with `CustomRepository` so I am wondering if there is an other way.

This is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/individualQuote/{id}", name="user_individualQuote", methods={"GET","POST"})
 **/
public function getIndividualQuote(Prospect $prospect,Car $car): Response
{
    return $this->render('user/_individualQuote.html.twig', [
        'prospect' => $prospect,

    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/carInfo/{id}", name="user_carInfo", methods={"GET","POST"})
 **/
public function getQuote(Car $car): Response
{
    return $this->render('user/_individualQuote.html.twig', [
        'car'=>$car

    ]);
}
```

This is my twig template :

```
<ul>
    {% for quote in agency.quotes %}
        {{ dump(quote.prospect.id) }}
        <li><a href="{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: quote.prospect.id,id:quote.car.id}) }}"> {{ quote.prospect.fullname }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Database:
*table 1*
car entity
[image: table 1]

```
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $model;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Prospect::class, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $prospect;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $power;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $gas;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $registration;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $insuranceExist;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getModel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function setModel(string $model): self
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBrand(): ?string
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    public function setBrand(string $brand): self
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProspect(): ?Prospect
    {
        return $this->prospect;
    }

    public function setProspect(?Prospect $prospect): self
    {
        $this->prospect = $prospect;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPower(): ?int
    {
        return $this->power;
    }

    public function setPower(int $power): self
    {
        $this->power = $power;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGas(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gas;
    }

    public function setGas(string $gas): self
    {
        $this->gas = $gas;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegistration(): ?string
    {
        return $this->registration;
    }

    public function setRegistration(string $registration): self
    {
        $this->registration = $registration;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsuranceExist(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->insuranceExist;
    }

    public function setInsuranceExist(bool $insuranceExist): self
    {
        $this->insuranceExist = $insuranceExist;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getBrand() . " " . $this->getModel();
    }
}
```

*table 2*
prospect entity
[image: table 2]

```
class Prospect
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $birthdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $phoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     *
     */
    private $guid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Car::class, mappedBy="prospect", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $cars;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Quote::class, mappedBy="prospect")
     */
    private $quotes;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=City::class, inversedBy="prospects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $city;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->quotes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function setBirthdate(\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(?string $phoneNumber): self
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGuid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->guid;
    }

    public function setGuid(string $guid): self
    {
        $this->guid = $guid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist() {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Car[]
     */
    public function getCars(): Collection
    {

        return $this->cars;
    }
}
```

Quote entity

[image: quote]

Comment: You can not pass the same parameter `id` twice. I recommend you rework your code to have more specific parameters, e.g. `prospect_id` and `car_id`.

Comment: when i change my parameter :`"@Route("/individualQuote/{prospect_id}""` and my twig template :`"<a href="{{ path('user_individualQuote', {prospect_id: quote.prospect.id}) }}`" i got this error :"Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "prospect"."

Comment: What is table 1 and table 2 representing? Which entities?

Comment: @MAZux i just edited my post: car and prospect entities

Comment: Is the Quote for a specific Car? You have no relation between a Car and a Quote except that they have the same Prospect, which can have many of each. How do you expect to match them up?

Comment: @ArleighHix you are right i think i have to do relation between Car en Prospect and not Quote and Car that was obvious ! I am woriking on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your db structure but, from what you've shown *I'm guessing* you have a `Quote` entity. To keep it simple you could just use the `Quote`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/individualQuote/{id}", name="user_individualQuote", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function getIndividualQuote(Quote $quote): Response
{    

    return $this->render('user/_individualQuote.html.twig', [
        'prospect' => $quote->getProspect(),
        'car'      => $quote->getCar(),    
    ]);
}
```

And in twig:

```
{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: quote.id}) }}
```

Comment: i fact i need to do something like this :`{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: quote.prospect.car.id}) }}`but i got "App\Entity\Car object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation." exception

Answer (score 0):

If you have no direct relation between the two entities then this is the example I found in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html):

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}/comments/{comment_id}")
 * @Entity("comment", expr="repository.find(comment_id)")
 */
public function show(Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
}
```

It appears that only the first entity will be automatically found by `{id}`. You must specify how to find additional entities.

Try this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/individualQuote/{id}/{car_id}", name="user_individualQuote", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @Entity("car", expr="repository.find(car_id)")
 */
public function getIndividualQuote(Prospect $prospect, Car $car): Response
{
}
```

And to build the path in twig:

```
{{ path('user_individualQuote', {id: prospect.id, car_id: car.id}) }}
```

Comment: as you can see i am using a for loop. This for loop working with Quote`agencies.quotes` like a filter of prospect in differents agencies(agency is an entity). `{id: quote.prospect.id}) }}"> {{ quote.prospect.fullname }}` is necessarry to get the list of prospect that i want.

Comment: But i tried your solution and i go a exception 'Variable "car" does not exist.'